# Get the frame of a line of text inside a UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, frame, cgrect

I have an UILabel with numberOfLines == 0. The label displays an NSAttributedString.

I'd like to get the frame of every line in the label. I mean, I'd like to get the frame of the first line of text, the frame of the second one and so on.

Is it possible?

Comment: What's the use of getting this frame?

Comment: I need to scroll the container scrollview to the exact frame of a line of text.

Comment: You will need to lay out your attributed string with TextKit. It tells you the frame of every line.

Comment: I never used TextKit, can you give me an example of how to achieve that?

Comment: Anyway, just to clarify, I don't want to define the frames to draw the lines, I just want to know at which frame each line will be drawn.